# Beginner JavaScript - HTML page display no initial value display

Tags: javascript

I'm more or less new to JavaScript and am going to attempt a very basic version of Hangman to get me going.

I'm starting out with trying to display a number of lives when the user first enters the page, this will decrement with every letter they choose that doesn't feature in the word.

My JavaScript in an external file is as follows:

```
var lives = 5;

//Display the number of lives the user has remaining
var showLives = function(){
    document.getElementById("livesLeft").innerHTML = lives;
}

//Will decrease lives each time incorrect letter is chosen
function decrementLives(){
    lives--;
    showLives();
}
```

The problem is when I initially load the HTML page, there is no value displayed for number of lives remaining, I expect it to say 5.

When I click anywhere on the body though(currently hard coded to call decrementLives() for testing purposes) it works exactly how I'd like.  Displaying 4, 3, n-1 with every click.

Any ideas as to why this first isn't initially showing up like 5 like I expect.  I've been thinking it might be possibly something to do with the lives variable scope?

Comment: Is your Javascript at the top of the page? If so, it's likely that your function is being called before the `#livesLeft` element exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually call the function on page load. For example in onload event:

```
window.onload = showLives;
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to call the function `window.onload = showLives();` ?

Comment: @DrCord you're not actually calling the function in that line of code, but rather assigning it.

Comment: The annoying thing was I originally did have window.onload = showLives(); but was having the same problem!  window.onload = showLives has done the trick.  Thanks for the explanation!